# "Unrecognized name: m01_order_datetime_gmt0" error in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Below is my script where I am getting an error of

> Error: Unrecognized name: m01_order_datetime_gmt0 at [9:19]

Code

```
`select
case
when number_of_bookings = 1 then '1'
when number_of_bookings = 2 then '2'
when number_of_bookings = 3 then '3'
else '>3' end as number_of_bookings,
count(user_id) as number_of_users,
date_trunc(date(m01_order_datetime_gmt0), month) as Booking_month
from
(select
 user_id,
 count(distinct order_id) number_of_bookings
from analyst_all_orders
where 1=1
and d181_business_platform_code is not null
and date(m01_order_datetime_gmt0) between '2018-03-01' AND '2018-08-31'
group by 1
order by 1) as a
group by 1
order by 1`
```

Comment: I can't give an exact answer, but I will point out that the `ORDER BY` you have in the subquery aliased as `a` is either incorrect, or at least pointless.  You should remove it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
`select
case
when number_of_bookings = 1 then '1'
when number_of_bookings = 2 then '2'
when number_of_bookings = 3 then '3'
else '>3' end as number_of_bookings,
count(user_id) as number_of_users,
date_trunc(date(m01_order_datetime_gmt0), month) as Booking_month
from
(select
 user_id,
 count(distinct order_id) number_of_bookings
 , M01_ORDER_DATETIME_GMT0
from analyst_all_orders
where 1=1
and d181_business_platform_code is not null
and date(m01_order_datetime_gmt0) between '2018-03-01' AND '2018-08-31'
group by 1
order by 1) as a
group by 1
order by 1`
```

(if the subquery doesn't pass the column up to the surrounding query, the surrounding query won't know about said colum)